# Movie with a robot that is drilled in the head

Tags: story-identification

There was a sci-fi movie where a robot was drilled in the head so that the main character can identify the good one from the bad one (I think the good one was the one got drilled. It was just a small hole in the forehead).

Does anyone know the title of this movie? I believe it was from maybe the 70s/80s. I think that in that movie there was also a large truck (where the tire is bigger than a human).

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [*Starship* (1984)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_%28film%29).  Saw this on HBO almost 30 years ago.

> On the remote mining planet Ordessa, the management uses killer military police androids to crack down on workers upset with the terrible conditions. Lorca (John Tarrant) and his mother Abbie (Donogh Rees) led the human underground resistance movement until Abbie was killed by androids. Now, Lorca and Suzi (Cassandra Webb) battle Captain Jowitt (Ralph Cotterill) and the brutal bounty hunter Danny (Hugh Keays-Byrne), with the help of the friendly android Grid (Deep Roy)

[image: Image of Grid]